# How to make a program stop and print inputs from lowest to greatest?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make it so it stops the program in any form of "stop" like StOp or STOP (case sensitive). Then how would I make it so it would print in order from lowest to greatest with the number first then name second?

```
names = []
while 1:
    grades = input("Enter your score followed by your name")

if not grades or grades.lower() == 'stop':
    break
    grade_name = grades.split(" ")
    grades.append(grade_name[0])
    names.append(grade_name[1])

for grade, name in sorted(zip(grades, names)):
    print (grades, name)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To check for `stop` case-insensitively, you can convert the input to lowercase and compare against `stop`.

   ```
   if not grades or grades.lower() == 'stop':
   ```
2. To sort the data and print in ascending order, you can use `zip` and `sorted`

   ```
   for grade, name in sorted(zip(grades, names)):
       print grade, name
   ```

   for Example

   ```
   grades = [2, 3, 1]
   names  = ["b", "c", "a"]
   for grade, name in sorted(zip(grades, names)):
       print (grade, name)
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   1 a
   2 b
   3 c
   ```

Comment: How come when I add it, the program doesn't loop anymore?

Comment: @user2998309 To help you understand that, I need to see the properly formatted latest code. Could you please update your question with correctly indented code with these changes?

Comment: @user2998309 But still the formatting is wrong. Look at the indentation in the question, it is very important. Does the code look like that only in your editor?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like that in my editor. It is indented in my editor. My post doesn't indent like my program does. Could you show me what you mean?

Comment: Now, your program adds the grades and names only when the user input is empty or `stop`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: It says something about break outside loop

Comment: @user2998309 The `if` condition should be intended, so that it will be inside the `while` loop

Comment: When I type stop, it still doesn't print in ascending order of names only.

Comment: @user2998309 Please update your question with your latest code so that I can check what the mistake is.

Comment: It is still the latest updated code. I used the print section you gave me, but still it doesn't print when I type stop.

Comment: It indeed helps me, but how would I set it to range from 10 to 100?

Comment: @user2998309 What should range from 10 to 100?

Comment: Range of the score since score can only be 10 -> 100, thank you sir.

Comment: @user2998309 You can check `if int(grade_name[0]) > 100 or int(grade_name[0]) < 0: print "error message"`